# Node server restarts itself

Tags: javascript, node.js

So i have this file "client.html" that sends a string to a node server

client.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="http://127.0.0.1:3000/search" method='get'>
        <input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="submit" value="search">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The server takes the input string and prints it out on the console. And after some time it should print "Something else".

index.js

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var util = require('util');

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.all('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/client.html');
}); 

app.get('/search', function(req, res) {
    var name = req.query.name;
    console.log(name);
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("Something else");
    }, 240000);
}) ;

//listen in a specific port
app.listen(port);

//check status
console.log('Server running at http://localhost:' + port);
```

What happens instead is that the the "name" variable gets printed out and then after some time, before printing out "something else", the "name" variable gets printed out again as if someone clicked on the send button on the form in the client. Need some help fixing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should answer to the client before the connection times out and the browser tries to reconnect:

```
 app.get('/search', function(req, res) {
   var name = req.query.name;
   console.log(name);
   setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("Something else");
   }, 240000);

   res.end("Searching ...");
}) ;
```

Comment: What if i want to send back some data after the searching is done? I can't write res.end(data) after the console.log("something else") cause the res.end("Searching ...") was executed before

Comment: @bazzone you cant after 240 seconds. Every connection would timeout. Have a look at websockets, especially http://socket.io